# Using re-usable component in Angular 6 with input properties

Tags: angular, typescript, input, components

I've got three components: product-details, product-card and product-quantity.

I use product-quantity in product-card but I want to use it (product-quantity) also in product-details (I don't want to use there product-card in product-details because I 'want to change style of product-card)

My product-card and product-quantity contain a few input property such as product, shopping cart etc.

**product-card.component.html**

```
    <div *ngIf="showActions && shoppingCart" class="card-footer">
    <button *ngIf="shoppingCart.getQuantity(product) === 0; else updateQuantity" (click)="addToCart()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
    <i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i>Add to Cart</button>
    <ng-template #updateQuantity>
    <product-quantity [product]="product" [shopping-cart]="shoppingCart">

    </product-quantity>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

**product-card.component.ts**

```
export class ProductCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('category') category: Category;
  @Input('product') product: Product;
  @Input('show-actions') showActions = true;
  @Input('shopping-cart') shoppingCart: ShoppingCart;

  category$;
  products$;

  constructor(
    private cartService: ShoppingCartService,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {}

  addToCart() {
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.product);
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.category$ = await this.categoryService.getCategory(this.product.category);
    this.products$ = await this.productService.getAll();
  }
}
```

**product-details.component.html**

```
<div class="card">
          <div *ngIf="product.imageUrl" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + product.imageUrl + ')'" class="card-img-top">
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="showActions && shoppingCart" class="card-footer">
            <button *ngIf="shoppingCart.getQuantity(product) === 0; else updateQuantity" (click)="addToCart()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
              <i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i>Add to Cart</button>
            <ng-template #updateQuantity>
              <product-quantity [product]="product" [shopping-cart]="shoppingCart">
              </product-quantity>
            </ng-template>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**product-details.component.ts**

```
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  id;
  product$;
  cart$: Observable<ShoppingCart>;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private cartService: ShoppingCartService,
    private categoryService: CategoryService
  ) {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.cart$ = await this.cartService.getCart();
    this.product$ = await this.productService.get(this.id);
  }

}
```

**product-quantity.component.ts**

```
export class ProductQuantityComponent {

  @Input('product') product: Product;
  @Input('show-actions') showActions = true;
  @Input('shopping-cart') shoppingCart: ShoppingCart;

  constructor(private cartService: ShoppingCartService) { }

  addToCart() {
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.product);
  }

  removeFromCart() {
    this.cartService.removeFromCart(this.product);
  }

}
```

When I serve my project I do not se quantity component but other elements are available to see. Where I have a bug? Can anyone explain me what I've done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please reduce your code to  [mcve]

Comment: Firstly, why do you use `await` instead promises or observer? Secondly
, are you insure that `*ngIf="showActions && shoppingCart"` is true? Give us values of these variables in console.log, please

Comment: await is just a temporary solution, I'm gonna refractor code as soon as I solve this issue, don't worry. My `product-details.component` does not see properties `showActions` and `shoppingCart`. A edited `product-details.component.html`: Added `product-quantity` and removed `product-card`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created `div` with `*ngIf` directive and created an `Input` property to send if `title`, `price` are allowed to show to the user. By default it's set to true but when I inject a component a set it to false and the details are not visible

Answer (score 0):

Use a div Template condition  if you want a button or if you want the component it is going depends in the condition.

```
<div *ngIf="condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>  

  <ng-template #thenBlock>
    <div >
        Quantity Component 
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #elseBlock>     
        <button type="button"  (click)="changeBoolValue()">ADD Button</button>
  </ng-template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-component)

Comment: @Lebek I modified the post and I put an example in **stackblitz**

Comment: I cannot to that. Let me explain you. I've got button `Add to Cart`, when i click it transforms into `quanity.component`. So if I'll implement your solution I suddenly get two elements one below another: `Add to cart` and `quantity.component`

Comment: I already modify my post. Take a look to this example [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-component)